# Angular2 Check if Location.back has history to go back?

Tags: angular, typescript, location

So I have a button that calls, `Location.back()` i want to show it when it has history available, is it posible to check if location has any history, or can go back?

Or is there a way of accessing the history miself?

Angular Version: `2.2.3`

HTML:

```
<div (click)="historyBack()">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
</div>
```

component:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component(...)
export class HomeComponent{
  hasHistory = false;
  constructor(
   private _location: Location
  ){
    this.hasHistory = //Magic code
  }
  historyBack(){
    this._location.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `$window.history.length` ?

Comment: I tried `window.history.length`, but it returns random numbers: 4, 3, even if there is no history, and `Location.back()` does not do anything

Comment: Mi bad, using window.history.length did the job

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `Angular 7` you can use `Router.navigated` property to check if any navigation event has occurred.

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private location: Location
) {
  this.hasHistory = this.router.navigated;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't mean you can navigate back. If you navigate forward and then back again, `this.router.navigated` will be `true`, but you couldn't navigate back from there...

Answer (score 4):

Tried many solutions out there-

1. `this.router.navigated` always returned `true` for some reason (maybe because I'm navigating to another page via `redirectTo` in routing).
2. I tried with `history.length` but that always returned 2.
3. Then tried to use `history.state` to check if doesn't contain any arbitrary data, then I can assume it's a fresh tab open without any history. But it was only setting `{navigationId: 1}` (by Angular) so was not useful when refreshing an existing tab with existing history.

Finally, I thought of using `sessionStorage` this way which is working fine for me.

In a global space (let's say in `app.component.ts`), I did this-

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    ).subscribe(() => {
        let navigations = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('totalNavigations'), 10) || 0;
        navigations++;
        sessionStorage.setItem('totalNavigations', navigations.toString());
    });
}
```

Now, when I want to go back to see if there is any history, I'm doing this-

```js
goBack(): void {
    const totalNavigations = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('totalNavigations'), 10);
    if (totalNavigations > 1) {
        this.location.back();    // Or history.back()
    } else {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-default-path')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript to view the last place the user visited:

```
document.referrer
```

[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

So, in your case, you can check if the user can go back, as follows:

```
historyBack() {
if (document.referrer) {
  this._location.back();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a component that has a "go back" button and problem is that I don't want to show it if history is empty/app is initially started from this view.

We tried various things like listening for route changes with rxjs `pairwise()`, `Router.navigated` (see accepted answer) and other stuff. The one that seems to work every time in various scenarios is `getState()` from [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location).

`this.location.getState()`
returns `{navigationId: 1}`

It doesn't reset when new tab is opened and then navigated to the view, but for my needs, that's fine.

It *does* work however, if I duplicate my tab when it is the very first view (perfect!)

---

If you don't want to use Angular's Location class, you can just access the same object from [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state)